# Help solve this specific linear schrodinger equation, please

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

$$\left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 - \frac{2}{r} + C\right]\phi(r) = E\phi(r)$$

where $C$ is a known function. I am just looking for some help on the strategy to solve explicitly  for $\phi(r)$. One thing I am having trouble understanding is how we can solve this equation without expressing $\phi(r)$ in terms of $E$, but it seems like it is done all the time:
http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_1-dimensional_box

Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shadock thats legit, but I feel like people here will probably know the specifics of SE better

Comment: This is not a problem, we need to use maths in chemistry and physics and in a lot of different subjects. If you want a good answer you may ask the question in ME. :-)

Comment: The particle in a box is a "simple" system in that the SE reduces to basically $\mathrm{d}^2\psi/\mathrm{d}x^2 = -k\psi$ and the general solution is quite obvious. When you have that $-2/r$ term, it gets a bit more irritating. Exactly what context are you trying to solve the SE in? The form of the SE that you are using makes me think the $\ce{He+}$ ion (where that function $C = 0$) - if I am not wrong you can use the [power series method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations). There is a name for the solutions, I think spherical Bessel functions.

Comment: @orthocresol Hey! Good question...the form of that function is actually the hartree fock mean field approximation integral, so you are spot on, I am trying to do the HF method for helium.

Comment: Ok, I'd better let someone who knows this topic answer :p

Comment: I don't know if that someone exists :), all these quantum chemistry books say this is the go to method besides DFT yet it seems pretty complicated to the "go to" method

Comment: Don't worry, there are lots of smart quantum people around; I'm sure they'll notice.

Comment: @user2879934 As orthocresol mentioned this problem looks like the Schroedinger equation for a hydrogen-like atom, apparently the $\ce{He+}$ ion. For this kind of problem you can't simply use the simple approach that works for the particle in the box. Traditionally this sort of equation was solved via the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) (a.k.a. power series solution). Nowadays you might rather want to employ the newer
procedure using ladder operators. Both of these methods should be covered in great detail in Quantum mechanics textbooks.